# Magento 1.9.4.0 PHP 7.2 Cron job problems

Tags: cron, php-7.2, magento-1.9.4.0

**My settings:**
Server OS ‪Debian 9.6‬
Plesk 17.8.11
Magento 1.9.4.0
PHP 7.2

When I run schedule task cron.sh I get this:

> Task "/httpdocs/cron.sh" successfully completed in 0 seconds, output:
>   /httpdocs/cron.sh: 1: /httpdocs/cron.sh: which: not found
>   /httpdocs/cron.sh: 1: /httpdocs/cron.sh: sed: not found
>   /httpdocs/cron.sh: 1: /httpdocs/cron.sh: expr: not found
>   /httpdocs/cron.sh: 50: /httpdocs/cron.sh: ps: not found
>   /httpdocs/cron.sh: 51: /httpdocs/cron.sh: cron.php: not found

Cron doesn't work. Where is the problem? Could you help, please

I think that the problem is with Plesk...

I setup crontab using SSH

```
crontab -e
*/5 * * * * sh /path/to/y
```

Answer (score 0):

ok try to this first access your cron.php on url

https://domain.com/cron.php your should not get error 404

second check if you have correct file permission on cron.sh and cron.php

I suggest to you use this for your cronjob

https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler

Do you have SSH Access for your hosting account?

If you don't, you may need to edit the cron.php file and look for the following line of codes:-

````
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, ‘win’) === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;

Add the following codes in a new line exactly after the above line of codes:-

$isShellDisabled = true;```
````